# Possible to do Anytime upgrade of Pro to Ultimate with a Home Prem to Ultimate Key?

Tags: windows-7, anytime-upgrade

I might have made a mistake, in that I bought an Anytime Upgrade of Win7 Home Premium to Windows 7 Ultimate for a Windows 7 Pro computer. I have tried a few times inserting the supplied key, but errors pop up saying:

> "The upgrade key is not valid. Please check the key and try again."

The computer is up to date. But I also know that MS has had problems in the past with the Anytime Upgrade and compatibility too.

thoughts?

Comment: ended up getting an open license upgrade from Win7 Pro to Win7 ENt... with software assurance (well work did). A bit pricey but I do get the free upgrade to Win8 when the time comes... keeping the Win7 Prem upgrade to Ultimate though... use it somewhere :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use a `Anytime Windows Home Premium to Ultimate` on a computer running Windows 7 Pro. It will not work. Depending upon where you bought it you may be able to return it:

1. [Refund](http://www.microsoft.com/mscorp/productrefund/refund.mspx)
2. [Items ordered from Microsoft Store online](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/Returns-Refunds)
3. [Upgrade Paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772579(v=ws.10).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot upgrade a Windows 7 Pro OS to Windows 7 Ultimate with a Windows Home Premium to Ultimate upgrade key.